# python code for mathematics graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

wrote some Python code to plot the coordinates of simple one dimensional linear mapping using matplotlib.

There is no warnings and errors, but no coordinates are entered in graph.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

result = [10]
result[0] = 1
a = 1.1
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)

for i in range(len(result)-1):
    result[i+1] = a*(result[i] - 1/2) + 1/2
    plt.plot(x, result[i], 'ro')

plt.xlim(0, 10)

plt.ylim(0, 10)

plt.axhline(0, color='b', ls='-', lw=0.5)

plt.axvline(0, color='b', ls='-', lw=0.5)

plt.xlabel(r'$x$', fontsize=18)

plt.ylabel(r'$x_{n+1}$', fontsize=18)

plt.title(r'Graphs of $x_{n+1} = a(x_{n}-\frac{1}{2}) + \frac{1}{2}$', fontsize=20)

plt.show()
```

Comment: May you include images with expected and observed results? Also `r` prefix is unnecessary for `xlabel()` and `ylabel()` calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

length of result is 1, hence the loop doesn't run at all.

Perhaps you wanted to do

```
result = [0 for i in range(11)]
```

or

```
result = np.zeros(11)
```

when you initiate result.

(Credit: abukaj for suggesting using np.zeros)

Edit:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

result = np.zeros(11)
result[0] = 1
a = 1.1
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)

for i in range(len(result)-1):
    result[i+1] = a*(result[i] - 1/2) + 1/2
plt.plot(x, result, 'ro')

plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 10)
plt.axhline(0, color='b', ls='-', lw=0.5)
plt.axvline(0, color='b', ls='-', lw=0.5)
plt.xlabel(r'$x$', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel(r'$x_{n+1}$', fontsize=18)
plt.title(r'Graphs of $x_{n+1} = a(x_{n}-\frac{1}{2}) + \frac{1}{2}$', fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

gives me

[image]

Comment: I would use `np.zeros(10)`

Comment: nice suggestion.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Cannot plot the coordinates still.  where should I rewrite to solve them ?

Comment: @abukaj In this case, where should I write np.zeros(10)?

Comment: @S.Ky at the first assignment to `result` (instead of `[10]` in your code)

Comment: I modified your function and get a graph, you might want to change your x-label to n perhaps.